# jquery and php using hover div and using fadeinout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, hover

ineed your help in php &jquery
im working in news site in news blok the image should be chang when a mouse move to defrent news title
this is the templat

```
<section class="box-nwes-con">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/sport-img.jpg" title="{title}" alt="{title}" />
</a>
<div class="news-box-con">
<div class="title-news-block"><a href="#">{title}</a></div>
<!-- START BLOCK : text_row -->
<div class="center-news">
<a href="#">
<p>{title}
</p>
</a> 
<div class="cler"></div>
</div>
<!-- END BLOCK : text_row -->
</div><!--End news-box-con-->
<div class="cler"></div>
</section>
```

I new in jquery but i think it's not hard work!!
how i can chang image when hover newstitle

hellllllllllllp pleas

Comment: If it's not hard work, why haven't you tried? And you need to be more clear on what you need.

Comment: i need to change image when a mouse over another title

Comment: The code you have provided does not describe enough honestly, where is the news title in your code? And I see only one image. Explain more.

Comment: yes one imge block i need to change this image evry time i move mouse to another news title

Comment: note :START BLOCK : text_row  this a block loop select news from DB

Comment: `<p>{title}
</p>` is the title that the user will hover on? And how do you know which image to show on which title?

Comment: yes its that .. i dont know how i do that how to change image out the block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your news title is the

in center-news div - please try add this to header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.center-news p').hover(
               function() { 
                  //on mouse enter
                  $('.box-nwes-con img').prop('src', 'image2.png');
           }, function() {
                  //on mouse out? remove if not needed..
                  $('.box-nwes-con img').prop('src', 'none.png');
           });
     });
</script>
```

Please let me know if you have any difficulty by adding comment and i'll try help more..

**UPDATE:**
Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzQ8f/

Comment: I would suggest use <div> with css background-image: instead of the img btw.. and use addClass to swap out what image to show on the block..

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmm my problem idont now English very well :(

Comment: lol, shouldn't really matter - is this solution close to what you are looking for? I'm updating my answer with a fiddle.. should do exactly what you want.